# Coinbase Connect (OAUTH2) - Preselect Wallet Currency

Tags: coinbase-api

When i redirect a user to the coinbase oauth url, the "BTC Wallet" in "Wallet Access" is always preselected. Is it possible to send an additional information as query parameter or scope to preselect the desired wallet currency (As example ETH).

[Coinbase OAuth Landing Page Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SM43g.png)

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. It is possible to request all wallets with an additional parameter "accounts=all". See [Coinbase Connect OAuth2 Reference](https://developers.coinbase.com/docs/wallet/coinbase-connect/reference). Not exactly the requestes future, but serves for the needed purpose.